# Ubuntu 18.04.3: Screen scrambling while using two monitors with a Think Pad Thunderbolt 3 Dock

Tags: multiple-monitors, lenovo, thinkpad, thunderbolt, docking

I have set up my new work equipment, which includes the following devices:

- Lenovo P1 Gen 2
- Think Pad Thunderbolt 3 Dock Gen 2
- 2 x HP Z32 80 cm (31,5" ) 4K-UHD Workstation-Monitor

The problem which occured during operation is that the monitors are not running stable. Additionally some screen rambling occurs (Image of the problem added at the bottom).

I am using the following Ubuntu version:

- Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
- Kernel: Linux 5.3.7-050307-generic
- Architecture: x86-64

Does anybody face the same problem as i did? How can I solve it?

[image: Random Screen Noises]

Comment: I had this issue. I was running a Linux 5.8 machine w/ Pop OS on a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Extreme Gen 3. Using a USB-C to DisplayPort adapter on the front port allowed me to use this in Mac OS without an issue, but that same setup in Linux I was having an issue. Also, I noticed the scrambling was isolated to the window I was using, so my guess is it's a software issue. My workaround was to ditch using the DisplayPort ports, and instead hook up the monitors using the HDMI ports.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem with a docking station in the past. The issue turned out to be the cable I was using, by switching to new DisplayPort cabled the issue was resolved.

Another thing to check would be your configured refresh rate. I think that docking station only supports 30 Hz when connected to two 4k Monitors.

On the other hand, I've ordered a similar configuration and will be able to test if I also have the issue soon. Do you mind sharing how you installed the 5.3 kernel, I see that 18.04.3 normally ships with 5.0. I had been thinking to install 19.10 to get the new kernel, but LTS stability would be nice.

Comment: I am using Ukuu (Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility) to install and manage the Linux kernel

Comment: Thanks. 
I'll update you here if I can reproduce the issue when my order arrives.

Comment: My laptop has arrived, and I am having the same issue with my dock (Thinkpad USB-C Dock Gen2), and Ubuntu 19.10 with Kernel 5.3.0-23-generic.

Comment: Did you find a fix?

Answer (score 0):

An update of the firmware of the USB-C dock fixed this issue for me. Unfortunately, you need to boot into windows to run the installer. Maybe you can get it working with wine. support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/acc500106

I realize now that this firmware does not help for your Thunderbolt based dock.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by upgrading the Ubuntu kernel.
I upgraded my Kernel from 5.4.0 to 5.7.0 and the problem was solved.

I used the following posts to install kernel 5.7.0:
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/06/install-kernel-5-7-ubuntu-linux-mint/

And following post to turn off the secure boot to avoid "boot/vmlinuz-5.7.0 has an invalid signature" error during rebooting to 5.7.0:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS

I hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not so sure that you can blame this on the kernel. I'm running 5.7.11 and I can't run the Thunderbold 3 workstation dock Gen 2 at some resolutions in Linux. I mean, it might be, but the jury seems out.

Comment: I mean, at least in my case it did work and also with two of my other colleagues. But yes you could be right to say that there may be other reasons for this problem. My sole intention was that as it helped me so maybe it could help others too :).